# How can i put my elements on right location for Code Generator

Tags: html, json, coordinates, generator, element

Hello guys i was developing a code generator like [Sketch2Code](https://sketch2code.azurewebsites.net/) and i got stuck on my JSON. I wanted to create HTML page using this example `myData` of a given html structure. imagine this is the example output of a hand drawn image and needs to be placed in a DOM. How can I place each element on the right coordinate? I didn't want to use absolute position for the top and left of the element, instead to make it work with bootstrap grid

```js
myData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Image",
    accuracy: 99.92,
    xmin: 122,
    ymin: 115,
    xmax: 275,
    ymax: 241,
    width: 153,
    height: 126
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    name: "Carousel",
    accuracy: 99.75,
    xmin: 223,
    ymin: 289,
    xmax: 867,
    ymax: 481,
    width: 644,
    height: 192
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    name: "Paragraph",
    accuracy: 99.98,
    xmin: 708,
    ymin: 562,
    xmax: 920,
    ymax: 667,
    width: 212,
    height: 105
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    name: "Paragraph",
    accuracy: 99.99,
    xmin: 135,
    ymin: 565,
    xmax: 382,
    ymax: 675,
    width: 247,
    height: 110
  },
  {
    id: 13,
    name: "Button",
    accuracy: 99.83,
    xmin: 206,
    ymin: 688,
    xmax: 345,
    ymax: 746,
    width: 139,
    height: 58
  },
  {
    id: 13,
    name: "Button",
    accuracy: 90.4,
    xmin: 758,
    ymin: 704,
    xmax: 859,
    ymax: 745,
    width: 101,
    height: 41
  }
];
```

Comment: can you give more information? what kind of a "code generator"?

Comment: wanted to create html code generator every element should be created based on the data inside the list. for example, if it is BUTTON the width = "width" and top=ymin and left=xmin. is there any way that I can use the bootstrap grid with this. generally what I want the most is to create the layout

Comment: you should stick on css bro.

Comment: Deniz, I think that @BiniamBehailu is aware that he needs a transformation of absolute positioning and sizing to achieve a relative/responsive layout. He asks about Bootstrap which is of course css. However, such transformation is a difficult task since it needs to guess the intents of the author wrt. the elements behavior and follow good UX principles at the same time. I guess it would make a DNN on its own.

Comment: I think this question should be reformulated, if I understand it correctly, you are asking the following: How to automatically transform a static layout in absolute coordinates to relative space incl. responsive behavior? You can either try a learning apporach or you can go the optimization way where you try to find the best grid fitting the input layout under some constraints - perhaps a (mixed?) integer linear programming problem.

Comment: @Isolin thanks but my original idea is converting sketched images to html-bootstrap website, like https://sketch2code.azurewebsites.net/ that's why I am asking this. the problem is converting my pixel values from the son file to bootstrap grid system. Based on the layout from the sketch. And I agree its kind of a DNN.

Answer (score 0):

you could use dynamic classes and html elements. the above example can be dynamic if you do something like this:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>
      This is a static template, there is no bundler or bundling involved!
    </h1>

    <script>
      const myData = [
        {
          id: 1,
          button: {
            type: "button",
            text: "Click Me!",
            width: 139,
            height: 58,
            pos: {
              top: 100,
              left: 20
            }
          }
        }
      ];

      const body = document.querySelector("body");
      const btn = document.createElement(myData[0].button.type);
      btn.style.position = "absolute";
      btn.innerHTML = `${myData[0].button.text}`;
      btn.style.width = `${myData[0].button.width}px`;
      btn.style.height = `${myData[0].button.height}px`;
      btn.style.top = `${myData[0].button.pos.top}px`;
      btn.style.left = `${myData[0].button.pos.left}px`;
      body.appendChild(btn);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks but, it's not the same button with the same width, height, and position, it's different with other values

Comment: are you able to give a better understanding what exactly you are trying to do? maybe with some imgs, drawings, gifs created with shareX or something? or at least please show us more code. what have you tried for now.

Comment: I am writing a sketch2code model same as this https://sketch2code.azurewebsites.net/, please check it. And I found it hard to create the layout algorithm

Comment: i believe you have to use absolute positions for this. i am not sure about using coordinates to place elements inside a HTML.

Comment: thanks! i tried absolute position and didn't get the result I wanted, that's why I'm asking if there is any way that I can use bootstrap grid

Comment: @BiniamBehailu check my answer, i did an update. maybe it helps.